# datagridview to excel

Tags: c#

iam adding reference of microsoft excel library 12.0
Add a reference to the ‘Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library’ to your project from COM components.

but iam not able to create this object...???
i included namespace in page but still iam not getting in intellisense whats wrong....

Excel.ApplicationClass ExcelApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();

Answer (score 2):

The error you are likely getting is

> 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass'
>   cannot be embedded. Use the applicable
>   interface instead.

What you need to do is use the Application class.  In other words, just change your code to

```
Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
```

Update: The above assumes you have set Excel as the alias for the appropriate namespace.  This can be achieved by adding the following at the top of your source

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

More info: [Classes and Interfaces in the Office Primary Interop Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247299%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Actually, I just managed to find the [tutorial](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-create-excel.htm) that I used to start with Excel.

Comment: i a code one has included Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 
but iam gettng microsoft.office.core

Comment: You should add reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, reference to microsoft.office.core will come automatically

Comment: Updated my answer a bit ago. See if that works for you.  Check out the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Download the [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) and add the EPPlus.dll as a reference on your C# project, and you can solve your problem with the below solution....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using OfficeOpenXml.Style;
using System.Drawing;


namespace Excel_Report
{
    public partial class MReport : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
        return;
    }

    private void ExcelOut(DataTable tbl)
    {

        using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            string DocName = "A_Report_" + DateTime.Now;
            DocName = DocName.Replace("/", "_").Replace(" ", "_");

            //Create the worksheet
            ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(DocName);

            //Load the datatable into the sheet, starting from cell A1. Print the     column names on row 1
            ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(tbl, true);
            ws.Cells[ws.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns(); ;

            //Format the header for column A-Z
            using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells["A1:U1"])
            {
                rng.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                rng.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;                      //Set Pattern for the background to Solid
                rng.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.FromArgb(79, 129, 189));  //Set color to dark blue
                rng.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.White);
            }


            //Write it back to the client

            byte[] renderedBytes;

            renderedBytes = pck.GetAsByteArray();
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=" + DocName + ".xlsx");
            Response.BinaryWrite(renderedBytes);
            Response.End();
        }
    }

    //This is the Save Report Click event
    protected void Save_RPT_BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Finding my GridView, so on your blank.aspx page create a Gridview 
        ContentPlaceHolder ContentPH = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("Main_CPH_01");
        GridView gridView001 = (GridView)ContentPH.FindControl("GridView1");

        //This tells the GridView to grab its Data from its DataSource 
        gridView001.DataBind();

        //Create a new DataTable to save the GridView's data
        DataTable RPT_DT01 = new DataTable();

        //Create a connection string and a query string both of which are using parts of a SqlDataSource that belong to the GridView
        string aConnString = SqlDataSource1_RPT.ConnectionString.ToString();
        string queryString = SqlDataSource1_RPT.SelectCommand.ToString();

        //Set the properties to connect to your database
        using (SqlConnection connection =
                   new SqlConnection(aConnString))
        {
        // Set the properties for the database query
            SqlCommand command =
                new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        //Open a connection to the database
            connection.Open();

       //Create a Sql Reader
            SqlDataReader reader01 = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                // Call Read before accessing data.
                reader01.Read();

                // Load the datatable with the data from the Sql reader
                RPT_DT01.Load(reader01);

                //Create the Excel File from the Data table
                ExcelOut(RPT_DT01);

                // Call Close when done reading.
                reader01.Close();
            }
        }
    }



    }
}
```